# Java stream list to index map

Tags: java, java-stream

How can I get a map from a list of strings, where the index is the key and the string is the value?

If I have such a list

```
List<String> list = List.of("foo","bar","baz","doo");
```

I want to get a `Map<Integer,String>` like

```
{0=foo, 1=bar, 2=baz, 3=doo}
```

When I do the following I get an error

```
static Map<Integer,String> mapToIndex(List<String> list) {
    return IntStream.range(0, list.size())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), i -> list.get(i)));
}
```

error

> Required type:
> int
> Provided:
> Object

When I cast it to int or Integer

```
static Map<Integer,String> mapToIndex(List<String> list) {
    return IntStream.range(0, list.size())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), i -> list.get((Integer) i)));
}
```

i get

> 'collect(java.util.function.Supplier, java.util.function.ObjIntConsumer, java.util.function.BiConsumer<R,R>)' in 'java.util.stream.IntStream' cannot be applied to '(java.util.stream.Collector<java.lang.Object,capture<?>,java.util.Map<java.lang.Object,java.lang.String>>)'

What I am missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) doesn't have a [`collect()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.ObjIntConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) method taking a [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) as parameter, so you have to use [`boxed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#boxed--) to convert it to a `Stream<Integer>` :

```
static Map<Integer, String> mapToIndex(List<String> list) {
    return IntStream.range(0, list.size()).boxed().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), list::get));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add boxing to convert `int`s to `Integer`s

```java
IntStream.range(0, list.size())
         .boxed()
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), i -> list.get(i)));
```